# Why is $(I+A)/(I-A)$ unambiguous?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

The following question is from Roger W. Brockett, *Finite Dimensional Linear Systems* ([Image of source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BztqW.png)):

> Ordinarily one does not use division notation when dealing with matrices because $A/B$ might be interpreted as $AB^{-1}$ or $B^{-1}A$ and these are not necessarily the same. Why is the notation $(I+A)/(I-A)$ unambiguous?

I do not know what (I+A)/(I-A) is supposed mean, let alone proving it is unambiguous.

So the question is what that notation mean, and preferably why is unambigous?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The claim is that $(I+A)(I-A)^{-1}=(I-A)^{-1}(I+A)$, so they can both be written as $(I+A)/(I-A)$ without ambiguity.  Obviously $A\ne I$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I agree that that's the claim, but I honestly wondering if the author did what I did and under-thought this statement. Even assuming $A\neq I$, it's not true that $I-A$ is necessarily invertible (eg $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$). Either the author meant to say $I-A$ is invertible or they made a mistake.

Comment: Yes, I was about to say that $I-A$ must be invertible

Comment: A useful fact: any polynomial of a matrix $A$ (in the constant term you put $I$) commutes with another polynomial of $A$. And also with the inverse, since by Cayley-Hamilton, the inverse is also a polynomial of $A$.

Comment: start from any associative algebra, the subalgebra generated by a single element in abelian.

Answer (score 9):

Matrices $A$ and $B$ need not commute. So, $AB^{-1} \neq B^{-1}A$ in general. However, your text is claiming that matrices $(I+A)$ and $(I-A)^{-1}$ do commute for all matrices $A$ where $(I-A)$ is invertible. This can be proven thusly;

$$(I+A)(I-A)^{-1}=(I-A)^{-1}+A(I-A)^{-1}$$

$$\therefore (I-A)(I+A)(I-A)^{-1}=I+(I-A)A(I-A)^{-1} $$

$$\therefore(I-A)(I+A)(I-A)^{-1}=I+A(I-A)(I-A)^{-1}$$

$$\therefore(I-A)(I+A)(I-A)^{-1}=I+A$$

This yields

$$(I+A)(I-A)^{-1}=(I-A)^{-1}(I+A)$$

So the notation $(I+A)/(I-A)$ is unambiguous for matrices of this specific form.$$$$(Note: the division symbol assumes and requires that $(I-A)^{-1}$ exist)

Comment: You've assumed that $A$ and $I-A$ commute in lines 2-3

Comment: @pancini:  they do commute; either way, their product is equal to $A-A^2$

Comment: @pancini They always do because $A(I-A)=(A-A^2)=(I-A)A$ for all matrices A.

Comment: Ah I see; thanks. Very nice answer.

Comment: Nice answer +1.  How did you come up with it?  I think you meant the matrices $(I+A) $ and $(I\color{red}-A)^{-1}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you... Not sure, Every once in a while I'll have a good idea....and I did mean $(I-A)^{-1}$. I'll edit that.

Comment: Should you say for all matrices $A$ for which $(I-A)$ is invertible?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Probably so... The author seems to be assuming it but I'll add it for clarity.

Comment: I suppose you can’t really talk about $(I-A)^{-1}$ if $I-A$ isn’t invertible

Answer (score 3):

A generalization of the answer by @Volk. If $A$ is some square matrix over a field $k$ and $p \in k[X]$ is a polynomial such that $p(A)$ is invertible, then $A$ and $p(A)^{-1}$ commute:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
 & p(A)^{-1} A &=& A \, p(A)^{-1} \\
\Leftrightarrow \quad & p(A) p(A)^{-1} A &=& p(A) A \, p(A)^{-1}\\
\Leftrightarrow \quad & A &=& A \, p(A) p(A)^{-1}\\
\Leftrightarrow \quad & A &=& A
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Here we used that $A$ and $p(A)$ commute (to see this, expand $A \, p(A)$ and $p(A) A$). It follows that also all non-negative integral powers $A^n$ of $A$ commute with $p(A)^{-1}$. Then for any polynomial $q \in k[X]$ also $q(A)$ and $p(A)^{-1}$ commute. In your example $p(X) = 1 - X$ and $q(X) = 1+A$.

Comment: Could we even say that two polynomials of the same matrix always commute? And inverse of polynomial of some matrix is also a polynomial of this matrix from C-H theorem.

Answer (score 0):

From
$$
(I-A)(I+A+A^2+A^3+A^4+\ldots)=I
$$
follows
$$
(I-A)^{-1}=I+A+A^2+A^3+A^4+\ldots
$$
and commutes with $I+A$.

More generally, $(I-A)^{-1}$ is a function of $A$ and so commutes with $A$ and then with $I+A$.

Comment: This requires more restrictions on $A$ to make the series in $A$ converge.